# Null exception on array

Tags: java, arrays, null, setter, getter

I'm very new to Java and programming and working on a class project, we're learning about i/o, arrays and objects and we have some pretty specific guidelines to follow.  When the compiler gets to "countryInfo[count].setName(name);" , it gives me

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.main(Main.java:53)

If I comment it out, the next line gives me the same error.
I'm sure there's much more efficient ways to re write this code, but since we're newbies we aren't allowed to do that.  I read quite a bit about Null exception before I asked... if I missed it somewhere I apologize. I'm lost :(

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
private static Country[] countryInfo = new Country[43];

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String name = "";
    String capital = "";
    String region = "";
    int region_Nbr = 0;
    int capital_population = 0;

    // TODO code application logic here
    String filename = "Countries.txt";
    String inputString;

    FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(filename);
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis1));
    inputString = br1.readLine();

    while (inputString != null) {
        int count = 0;
        System.out.print(inputString + "\n");

        name = inputString.substring(0, 13).trim();
        //System.out.print(name + ", "); //echo

        capital = inputString.substring(24, 36).trim();
        //System.out.print(capital + ", ");//echo

        region = inputString.substring(40, 56).trim();
        //System.out.print(region + ", "); //echo

        region_Nbr = Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(64, 66).trim());
        //System.out.print(region_Nbr + ", ");//echo

        capital_population = Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(72, inputString.length()).trim());
        //System.out.print(capital_population + "\n");

        countryInfo[count].setName(name);
        countryInfo[count].setCapital(capital);
        countryInfo[count].setRegion(region);
        countryInfo[count].setRegionNum(region_Nbr);
        countryInfo[count].setPopulation(capital_population);
        inputString = br1.readLine();

        count++;
    } //end while

}
```

}

```
public class Country {

private String name;
private String capital;
private String region;
private int region_Nbr;
private int capital_population;



public void setName(String w) {
    this.name = w;

} //end get name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add:

```
countryInfo[count] = new Country();
```

before

```
countryInfo[count].setName(name);
```

Answer (score 3):

You never fill your array with objects. currently you have an array but it is empty and filled with just nulls. The solution is to create objects to fill it with before using. Think of an array as being similar to an egg crate. You can't cook with eggs from the crate til you fill it with eggs first.

```
    countryInfo[count] = new Country(); // **** add
    countryInfo[count].setName(name);
    countryInfo[count].setCapital(capital);
    countryInfo[count].setRegion(region);
    countryInfo[count].setRegionNum(region_Nbr);
    countryInfo[count].setPopulation(capital_population);
    inputString = br1.readLine();
```

---

Edit, you state:

> I'm not sure I understand why I needed to add that line, I thought that private static Country[] countryInfo = new Country[43];

When you create the array objects, also known as an array of reference type, you create a collection of empty variables, variables that are given the default value for any reference variable, null. This is different from creating an array of primitive type which will initialize the array to the default of the primitive (0 for ints, false for booleans, etc...).

Again, this is akin to creating an empty egg carton or a parking lot. In order for the array to be filled with objects, **you must put the objects into the array yourself.** You need to fill a parking lot with cars before you can select one and drive one off. Just having a parking lot with empty spots will not be useful to you.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help. I'm not sure I understand why I needed to add that line, I thought that                                 private static Country[] countryInfo = new Country[43];                  wouldve done the same thing. Interesting.

Comment: @user2368407 - This statements **allocates memory** for 43-element array of type `Country` objects, but **does not create** these 43 instances.